# Open VPN options error: --tls-auth fails with 'ta.key': no such file or directory

Tags: linux, openvpn

I installed Open VPN and generated .crt and .key files but I could not able to generate ta.key file which gives me  options error : --tls-auth fails with ta.key : No such file or directory. How could I create this file. I couldn't find ta.key in any directory of Open VPN.

Answer (score 19):

To generate the tls-auth key:

```
openvpn --genkey --secret /etc/openvpn/ta.key
```

Answer (score 6):

If you do not have a *ta.key*, of course *tls-auth* will fail. You may:

1. drop the *tls-auth* instruction altogether. This is not a major dent in your security: [the Manual](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Hardening#Useof--tls-auth) in fact states:

> This feature by itself does not improve the TLS auth in any way, although it offers a 2nd line of defense if a future flaw is discovered in a particular TLS cipher-suite or implementation (such as CVE-2014-0160, Heartbleed, where the tls-auth key provided protection against attackers who did not have a copy). However, it offers no protection at all in the event of a complete cryptographic break that can allow decryption of a cipher-suite's traffic.

2. or you may now generate the *ta-key*:

   ```
   openvpn --genkey --secret /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys/ta.key
   ```

   it is not too late for this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I messed up with my /etc/openvpn/server.conf while editing.

Reinstalling OpenVPN fixed my issue.

Recommend to do a backup before a edit.